# Nightwatch.js get value from input and use it in next step

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run Nightwatch script which will open a url, then it will getValue from an Input and will use that value in the next page.

Please see the following code:

```
var conf = require('../../nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js');

module.exports = {
    'nightwatch flow': function (browser) {
        var first_name;
        browser
            .url('http://example:3000')
            .getValue('input[name="first_name"]', function(result){
                first_name = result.value;
            })
            .setValue('input[name="amount"]', 101)
            .click('input[name=continue]')
            .clearValue('input[name="first_name"]')
            .setValue('input[name="first_name"]', first_name)
            .click('button[name=next]')
            .end();
    }
};
```

the `setValue('input[name="first_name"]', first_name)`
gets "undefined"

first_name parameter is being updated inside a callback function.
I need that setValue function will use the updated value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be related to this issue https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1132. Calling `setValue` after `clearValue` seems to cause issues.

Comment: Hi thanks, It's not the case, I've found a workaround. Will post a solution in few minutes

Answer (score 5):

I've found a workaround:

```
var conf = require('../../nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js');

var first_name;

module.exports = {
    'nightwatch flow': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://example:3000')
            .getValue('input[name="first_name"]', function(result){
                first_name = result.value;
            })
            .setValue('input[name="amount"]', 101)
            .click('input[name=continue]')
            .clearValue('input[name="first_name"]')
            .setValue('input[name="first_name"]', "", function(){
                browser.setValue('input[name="first_name"]', first_name)
            })
            .click('button[name=next]')
            .end();
    }
};
```

The solution is to use the browser.setValue again inside a callback.

Comment: If you want just simple copy-paste you can even do ```browser.getValue('.selector', res => browser.setValue('.another', res.value));```

Comment: the problem you're running into here is because of nightwatch's command queue. If you simply wrapped a single setValue function inside of a browser.perform() it would do what you want. The problem is that your original setValue was passing first_name prior to the getValue callback even running. see https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue